# How can I retrieve 2FA recovery codes for a user in ASP.NET Core Identity?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, two-factor-authentication

I'm currently working on an ASP.NET Core identity project. I need to create a page where the user can see the two-factor recovery codes that they have left to use. I've noticed that the recovery codes for a user is stored in the "ASPNetUserTokens" table in the default schema that ASP.NET Core Identity creates.

How can I retrieve the recovery codes for a user in my code?

I've had a look at the "GetAuthenticationTokenAsync" method on the UserManager class but was not sure how to go about using this.

Comment: Are you talking about showing them at all, or re-displaying them at some later point. The recovery codes have to be shown to the user immediately after setting up 2FA. Afterwards, they cannot be retrieved again. That's by design.

Comment: I know that as soon as you use a recovery code, you cannot use it again so I'd like a page to show the codes that the user has left to use. This is only after setting up 2FA and only whilst they are logged in - I already have it displaying the newly generated codes immediately after setting up 2FA but I'd like a user to be able to return to see their usable recovery codes at a later date. It's something that Google allows you to do with their 2FA login.

Answer (score 4):

I implemented it like this.

```cs
var internalLoginProvider = "[AspNetUserStore]";
var recoveryCodeTokenName = "RecoveryCodes";
var token = await _userManager.GetAuthenticationTokenAsync(user, internalLoginProvider, recoveryCodeTokenName);
```

Here are the links to the implementations and constants that I referred to.

[InternalLoginProvider](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/52eff90fbcfca39b7eb58baad597df6a99a542b0/src/Identity/Extensions.Stores/src/UserStoreBase.cs#L983)

[RecoveryCodeTokenName](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/52eff90fbcfca39b7eb58baad597df6a99a542b0/src/Identity/Extensions.Stores/src/UserStoreBase.cs#L985)

[GetTokenAsync in CountCodeAsync](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/52eff90fbcfca39b7eb58baad597df6a99a542b0/src/Identity/Extensions.Stores/src/UserStoreBase.cs#L1021)